# Flash CS6 AS3: Click listener on overlapping movieclips only fires top movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, events, movieclip, flash-cs6

I have several Movieclips which overlap one another, each one has a different graphic of a body part. I would like the user to be able to click on a body part and it highlights.

I've set up event listeners to detect a click on the movieclips and to then apply a colorTransform. The problem is that the top movieclip also gets selected, and not the one's below even though the movieclips have transparent BitMap (PNG) images in them.

Is there a way I can create the hotspots to support only opaque pixels?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260893/making-a-flash-country-map

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with TouchEvents, so ended up converting all the PNG files to vectors by breaking them apart and using the Magic Wand tool to delete the transparent pixels.

Comment: Depending on hoy many vectors you have, performance could be seriously  affected in mobile. On the post I linked to, there was one library for using PNGs that ignore transparent pixels for clicks. Also I offered a solution which is the best one in terms of performance (I had to develop it myself for a mobile app). I could post the code for that if you wish.

Comment: That would be great if you could. Thanks.